# Move uploaded file to root directory

Tags: php, file, upload, directory, root

I'm making a content management system for a website I built. I want the system to be discrete, so I made it exist in only one PHP file, called '_admin.php'. All the content displayed in this file comes from includes that I store in a sub-folder called 'admin' (out of the way).

The photos used on the website are stored in an 'assets' folder that also sits in the root dir. The admin page has direct access to the assets folder, as it is also in the root. But the upload file script sits a few directories into the 'admin' folder and I want the uploaded files to be stored in the assets folder.

The `move_uploaded_file()` method takes the destination path for the file, but it requires a direct path. I try using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, but the resulting directory doesn't seem to have any of my files. If I use `getcwd()` in a doc in the root, it returns the actual file structure that I can use. The same if I echo out `__FILE__`. But I've experimented with this SERVER constant a lot and I can't locate my website with it.

Since the script that uploads the images is called as a form action, I can't pass the root directory as a variable.

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong, anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

edit **

```
//See if Files array contains new files
if (!empty($_FILES['file'])){

    foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $name){

        $error = $_FILES['file']['error'][$key];
        $temp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $dir = getcwd();
        $move_file = move_uploaded_file($temp_name, "$dir/temp/$name");

        if (($error == 0) && ($move_file)){

            $uploaded[] = $name;

        }else{

            die($error);

            }   



        }

        echo __FILE__;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo __DIR__;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        exit();

    }
```

The upload script I'm currently using. This script works fine because I'm storing the images in the same directory as the script. I just don't know how to store them in my root.

Comment: can you post your code related to this matter?

Comment: It's a bit all over the place. The site uses like 30 files haha. I'll update the post with the upload script.

Answer (score 0):

I would specify the full absolute file path if you can. I set this via `define()` in a config file for my CMS. On install you figure out what that path is and set it.

```
define("BASEFILEPATH", "/home/.../[webroot]");   // The base file path for the website
```

You may be looking for something more general, but you could have some sort of install script where the user can enter basic info into a form, such as username, pwd, etc. and you could have them enter this path as well.

Comment: I haven't actually heard of this function before, it looks pretty cool. It seems like the constants only exist as long as the script though, so inside my upload script, the constant doesn't exist. Is this correct? Thanks!

Comment: Yes you are correct that it only exists in the script it's set in. I include my config file in every script in my CMS, so for me it's not an issue. You could do the same, just set it in a file and include that file at the top of whatever other scripts you want to use it in.

Comment: But if I could successfully target the config file, I'd be able to target the assets folder anyway, meaning there'd be no need for the config. My issue is targeting directories above the one that holds my upload script. You have anymore thoughts? I might repost the question with a different title. Thanks.

Comment: I just discovered that the reason $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] isn't working is because of my host. I'm hosting my site with 000webhost (for development, because it's free), and apparently this is a known issue. Until I finish the site, I'll store the root in a session variable. Thanks for the help, though :)